# How to ensure mandatory parameters are passed into a Spring MVC controller method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, parameters, bean-validation

Given a Spring-MVC controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/method")
public void method(@RequestParam int param1,
                   @RequestParam int param2) { /*...*/ }
```

If parameters are missing in the request URL, an error is reported, e.g:

> JBWEB000068: message Required int parameter 'param1' is not present

I need to move the parameters into a single model class yet keep exactly the same GET request URL. So have modified `method`'s parameter to `MyModel model`, which contains `param1` and `param2`.

This works if `@RequestParam` is omitted but the snag is **no error is reported if parameters are missing**. If, on the other hand `@RequestParam` is included, a parameter named "model" is expected in the GET request. Is there a way to make model parameters mandatory yet keep the same request URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use JSR-303 annotations to validate the object (and don't use primitives but the Object representations in that case).

```
public class MyObject {
    @NotNull
    private Integer param1;

    @NotNull
    private Integer param2;

    // Getters / Setters

}
```

Controller method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/method")
public void method(@Valid MyObject obj) { /*...*/ }
```

If you don't have a JSR-303 provider (hibernate-validator for instance) on your classpath create a `Validator` and use this to validate your object.

Links.

1. Spring MVC [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)
2. Spring Validation [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)

Comment: Just suggestion, it would be great if you add information along with your solution as " why he is not getting any error while omitting @RequestParam and getting error while adding back." - that might help him to understand the basis behind how spring handling model Object as Request like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372957/how-does-spring-mvc-controller-method-parameter-work

Comment: @MDeinum Many thanks for the solution - am quite new to this type of thing and hadn't come across JSR-303 before. Nice compact syntax and works a treat!

Answer (score 0):

You can try @ModelAttribute and method=RequestMethod.POST:
In your controller:

```
//...
@RequestMapping(value="/method", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String add(@ModelAttribute("modelName") ModelClass form)
{
   //.. your code
}

//..
```

In your JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="f" %>

//.. some code 

<f:form action="method" method="post" modelAttribute="modelName">

</f:form>
```

If you are restricted to GET requests only, you might not be able to use a separate ModelClass. You need to resort to request parameters in that case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The actual method has to be a GET request and is returning JSON data (so the JSP bit isn't relevant). Have tried using `@ModelAttribute` but it doesn't seem to make any difference - the missing parameter error doesn't get reported.

Answer (score 0):

add ( ,@BindingResult result) in your parameter to bind the errors to all parameter. And you can check if the error exist using result.hasErrors()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).